# What is the highest accuracy for classifying cats and dogs from CIFAR-10?

Tags: deep-learning, accuracy

Resnet, [DenseNet](https://github.com/bamos/densenet.pytorch), and other deep learning algorithms achieve average accuracies of 95% or higher on CIFAR-10 images. However, when it comes to similar images such as cats and dogs they don't do as well. I am curious to know which network has the highest cat vs dog accuracy and what it is.

I am aware of [Cat vs Dog competition on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats) and such, but none that I know of are on CIFAR-10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highest accuracy should be around %91.5. I have explained the details [here](http://www.miladiouss.com/cats-vs-dogs/).

Answer (score 0):

Google's AutoML for large scale image classification has come up with    [NASnet](https://ai.googleblog.com/2017/11/automl-for-large-scale-image.html) which now by far produces the best results(96.2% accuracy    on the top5) on ImageNet image classification ([Nasnet implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim/)).

Imagenet has both cats and dogs as pre-trained classes but they are further divided into many sub categories of cats and dogs.